# Python: Search text file and write block of lines including previous line to another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I am searching through a text file and want to copy and write a block of lines associated with a match in another text file.  Once i find the search criteria, i want to copy/write out the previous line and next 9 lines (total of 10 lines) out to a file for each match.

Example input file to be search

```
Line 1: File sent to xyz blah blah:
                             Line 2: Search Criteria here
                             Line 3
                             Line 4
                             Line 5
                             Line 6
                             Line 7
                             Line 8
                             Line 9
                             Line 10

Line 1: File sent to xyz blah blah:
                             Line 2: Search Criteria here
                             Line 3
                             Line 4
                             Line 5
                             Line 6
                             Line 7
                             Line 8
                             Line 9
                             Line 10
```

Code i have started:

```
searchList = []
searchStr = "Search Criteria here"

with open('', 'rt') as fInput:
    previous = next(fInput)
    for line in fInput:
        if line.find(searchStr) != -1:
            searchList.append(previous)
            searchList.append(line.lstrip('\n'))


with open('Output.txt','a') as fOutput:
    OutPut.write("\n".join(searchList))
```

The code above saves to a file like this with spaces in between the first and second line:

```
mm/dd/yyy  hh:mm:ss.MMM File sent to xyz:

                             Line 2: Search Criteria here

mm/dd/yyy  hh:mm:ss.MMM File sent to xyz:

                             Line 2: Search Criteria here
```

I want save all 10 lines, exactly as they are in the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read the file and find the line numbers that match. Keep track of the line numbers for later.

```
all_lines = []
match_lines = []

with open('in_file.txt', 'r') as fInput:
    for number, line in enumerate(fInput):
        all_lines.append(line)
        if searchStr in line:
            match_lines.append(number)
```

Then, loop over the `match_lines` list and output the lines you care about from `all_lines`:

```
num_lines_before = 1
num_lines_after = 10
with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as fOutput:
    for line_number in match_lines:
        # Get a slice containing the lines to write out
        output_lines = all_lines[line_number-num_lines_before:line_number+num_lines_after+1]
        fOutput.writelines(output_lines)
```

To test this, I'm going to create a `io.StringIO` object to read/write a string as a file, and ask for one line before and two after:

```
import io

strIn = """This is some text
12345
2 searchforthis
34567
45678
5 searchforthis
63r23tf
7pr9e2380
89spver894
949erc8m9
100948rm42"""

all_lines = []
match_lines = []
searchStr = "searchforthis"

# with open('in_file.txt', 'r') as fInput:
with io.StringIO(strIn) as fInput:
    for number, line in enumerate(fInput):
        all_lines.append(line)
        if searchStr in line:
            match_lines.append(number)

num_lines_before = 1
num_lines_after = 2



# with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as fOutput:
with io.StringIO("") as fOutput:
    for line_number in match_lines:
        # Get a slice containing the lines to write out
        output_lines = all_lines[line_number-num_lines_before:line_number+num_lines_after+1]
        fOutput.writelines(output_lines)    
        fOutput.write("----------\n") # Just to distinguish matches when we test
    
    fOutput.seek(0)
    print(fOutput.read())
```

Gives this output:

```
12345
2 searchforthis
34567
45678
----------
45678
5 searchforthis
63r23tf
7pr9e2380
----------
```

Comment: Thanks @pranav hosangadi.  I have an updated requirement.  I still want to write the entire block of text to a text file, but would also like to parse each line into a .csv file to be opened in excel.  What would you recommend?

Comment: @DChase I'm not sure what you mean. Does each line already contain data that would make sense in a CSV? I suggest using [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)'s `writerow()` method, but I really need more information to make a meaningful recommendation. If you're having trouble using `csv.writer` and can't figure it out, feel free to post another question with details. I'll be glad to answer if you share the link here.

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know if i still have questions.  Thank you.